# VS2015 cordova emulator for windows phone 8.1 fails

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I deploy a cordova app from visual studio 2015 CTP 5 (running on Windows 8.1 enterprise x64) on a windows 8.1 mobile phone emulator I get the following error:

```
Error   Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor 
named '169.254.72.195:8116'.  
The remote debugger is not an acceptable version.
```

I've installed the latest version of the windows phone 8.1 SDK and emulators through Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5.

The emulator is starting and is getting into windows, but when it tries to deploy the app it fails.
Here is the output from the build/deploy process:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: <Project Name>, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(102,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  D:\Dev\Mobile\<Project Name>\<OneShare Mobile>>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\glvgt5lz.2qp\packages\vs-mda
2>------ Deploy started: Project: <project name>, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone (Universal) ------
2>Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named '169.254.72.195:8116'.  The remote debugger is not an acceptable version.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've checked that the emulator has that exact ip address and it has an internet connection since I can get to http://www.google.com

VS2015 reports an error during build and if I say yes to the question if I want to continue I get this error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
```

When I try the windows 8 or android emulator I have no problems.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Luckily is there a workaround, a manual deployment through the "Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1" program works.

Comment: This seems to work, please add it as an answer so I can close the question. It might be a good idea to point out that the user needs to go to the folder where the app was saved after debug build: 

    %project folder%\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\AppPackages%

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, but there is a workaround. A manual deployment through the "Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1" program will work.

You can find the package to deploy in the *"\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\AppPackages"* folder. Note that *Debug* is the build configuration and *Windows* is the target platform.